# Can I constrain one type parameter based on another type parameter in Golang?

Tags: go, generics

I'd like to create a generic method in Go that accepts a constrained parameter of type T and returns type R which is deterministic based on type T.  Here is what I've tried:

```
func genericsTest[T string | int, R int | bool](val T) R {
    switch any(val).(type) {
    case string:
        return R(1)
    case int:
        return R(true)
    }
}
```

I assume the issue here is there's no way for the compiler to infer R based on T, so attempts to cast the literals to type R fail because R could be either int or bool.  Is there a way to guarantee R's type based on type T?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this with unions of predeclared types, i.e. you can't tie together `T` and `R` directly. There isn't any actual relationship between them, beside your arbitrary "mapping".

The closest I can imagine is to define an interface that formalizes your type mapping and restrict what types can implement it:

```
type Mappable[T int | bool] interface {
    ~string | ~int
    As() T
}
```

The interface `Mappable` can be satisfied only by types with underlying type `string` or `int` that have a method `As() T`, where `T` is constrained to the your result types.

And then you implement it the way it makes sense to you:

```
type String string

func (s String) As() int {
    return 1
}

type Int int

func (n Int) As() bool {
    return true
}
```

And finally you constrain `T` in your function to `Mappable[R]`:

```
func genericsTest[R int | bool, T Mappable[R]](val T) R {
    return val.As()
}
```

Call it:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println(genericsTest(String("foo")))
    // prints 1

    fmt.Println(genericsTest(Int(1)))
    // prints true

}
```

**NOTE 1**: this doesn't prevent you from defining `func (s String) As() bool`. I don't have a solution for that.

**NOTE 2**: this solution works only with Go 1.21 and above, when type inference [was extended](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/60353) with interface assignability rules.

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/wlMMkN-iSWV